# Lazy loading in primefaces component

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have problem with lazy loading from my entity to my dataScroller.

Here is bulk from `my.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
  <p:dataScroller value="#{userBean.lazyModel}" var="user" chunkSize="10" lazy="true"> 
  <f:facet name="loader">
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="More" icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-s"/>
  </f:facet>

  <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%" columnClasses="logo,detail">
    <p:outputPanel>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
    <h:outputText value="Id:"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{user.id}" style="font-weight: bold"/>

    <h:outputText value="name:"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" style="font-weight: bold"/>

  </h:panelGrid>
</p:outputPanel>
</h:panelGrid>
</p:dataScroller>
```

And here is the `LazyDataModel` specification

```
 private LazyDataModel<User> lazyModel; 
   @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<User>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public List<User> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
                List<User> data = userService.getUsersFromTo(0 , first + pageSize);  
                this.setRowCount(data.size());
                return data;
            }
        };
    }

    public LazyDataModel<User> getLazyModel() {
        return lazyModel;
    }
```

Everything should work similarly like infinite scrolling in facebook. But there is a problem. I get 10 Users and after roll down I get another 10 Users but they are same as previous(same id names etc..)
I tried to debug it. And everything seems to work fine. Returned data in load function contains right data... Anyone face same problem or am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this

```
userService.getUsersFromTo(0 , first + pageSize);
```

rather be

```
userService.getUsersFromTo(first , first + pageSize);
```

in the first case the first ten of your users will always be the same, but the number of the users returned on each step will increase, it could be the cause of your issue

Comment: Yes this solve problem with duplicity but there is another problem that the button for next data disappear after first call... But partially you answer on my question. thx